# Writing to MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I've some some light database programming in school, before, but I'm trying to learn best practices now that I'm writing more sophisticated applications. Writing to a MySQL database isn't hard, but I'm wondering what a best practice is for having distributed applications write to a remote database on Amazon EC2.

As of right now, I'll have a MySQL database hosted in the cloud that's able to receive incoming connections. I questioned this as by default, it only enabled the local host to connect to it.

Is there a more secure or professional way to write to a MySQL instance in the cloud than just doing some kind of DbConnect, hard coding my server's online host name, root username and password? I just don't want to make a production application that's not accessing the database in the best fashion.

Thanks! You guys are always awesome.

Comment: Can you run other applications on the host that runs your MySQL database?

Comment: I suppose I could, but would that make it any more secure? I guess my question is, is my method bad?

Comment: Also, you're saying you want to access the database in “best fashion”. What exactly does that mean to you? Most convenient? Most efficient? Most secure? Also, since you mention, security, what kind of attack are trying to defend against?

Comment: Really, just all around. I want to know one, is the way I'm doing it now bad and if so, two, what is the most common way to read and write to a remote database within an application?

Comment: @Jack I would recommend you get a good book on ADO.NET and C#. I am certain APress has one that would be sufficient. Maybe, this one?  http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-C-Databases-Novice-Professional/dp/1590594339/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1328979465&sr=8-4

Answer (score 1):

the most viable to date option for database work is to use something like entity framework
your model is the model, your database connection sits on its own and you can easily port the application to another database provider if need... I.E   mysql to msSQL without really having to do much in the way of work.

Entity framework code first is the easiest i think to port over.   Also for mysql you just need the mysql.net connector  from the provider themselves, this works with entity framework.

also by working with models and using linq you further help reduce prodlems with SQL injection as you wont actually be writing or sending any SQL.

Given that, should you have a massive database, EF is a pain in the butt and is really slow and for this a simple database class would do,  you can have a few functions like this:

```
private readonly MySqlConnection _conn = new MySqlConnection();
private MySqlCommand _myCommand = new MySqlCommand();

private readonly string _dbConn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"];

public void Closedb()
{
    try
    {
        _conn.Dispose();
        _conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public void UpdateDatabaseWithSql(string mysql)
{
    Closedb();

        _conn.ConnectionString = _dbConn;
        _conn.Open();


    _myCommand= new MySqlCommand(mysql,_conn);

    _myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Closedb();
}
```

a DB connection for mysql looks like this, in the web.config file:

```
<add name="MvcCustomContext" 
     connectionString="server=[ip];User Id=[user];password=[pass];Persist Security Info=True;database=[dbname]" 
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

hope this helps

Comment: This looks like plain ole ADO.NET to me.

Comment: that's because the bottom bit is, i have it with my entity for bulk work because EF is just too slow for the size of databases I work with, dont get your point though :-)

Comment: It just seems that every time I turn around there is a new buzzword around the same technology. It drives me nuts. I don't know why MS can't leave well-enough alone. Anyhow, good answer +1. I would only add that if the OP isn't really familiar with .NET db programming, then he/she should learn ADO.NET. It is the core that all of this other new hype is built around. Anyways, if EF isn't scalable, why use it at all?

Comment: because with mvcscaffolding for example you can do a database driven website in half a day, with all the code more or less completed.  EF too is not really a buzz word the concept has been around for many many years under a different name and the MVC model is actually just a design pattern from the dawn of time :-)

Comment: I have no problem with design patterns: just that Microsoft can't seem to settle on one. Anyways, I wasn't talking about MVC. Also, beginners shouldn't be starting out with abstractions and design patterns but with the actual core technology. After they learn that, then it is time to start learning the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have another application running on the server and listening a port on TCP to make the actions on the database. You can encrypt the message and decrypt on server application, having a safe username/password and data traveling.

Comment: You can encrypt connections to MySQL too. How would this be any better?